# Firebase onChildAdded not always called

Tags: android, firebase

I have a Firebase database to save user specific data in my android app. To retrieve the data I use the ChildEventListener to get the data at start up.

```
        userRef = new Firebase("https://XXX.firebaseio.com/users_data/" + authData.getUid());

        // Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
        userEventListener =  new UserChildEventListener();

        userRef.addChildEventListener( userEventListener );
```

Most of the time everything works fine. The onChildAdded function is called and data is added locally. But there is some instances where it is not called. I checked that the authentication is working (other data in different node is loading). I changed the log level of Firebase to DEBUG and when it works it looks like this for every subnode:

> D/EventRaiser(24587): Raising /users_data/google:XXX: CHILD_ADDED: { bel_activce: active }
>   D/FirebaseDataHelper(24587): onChildAdded: bel_active

When it doesn't work it is just (without the onChildAdded call):

> D/EventRaiser(25553): Raising /users_data/google:XXX: CHILD_ADDED: { bel_active: active }

What exactly does this Raising log mean? It seems like the data is being updated but for some reason the callback is not called?

Thank you for your help.

UPDATE

Based on @FrankvanPuffelen feedback I checked the onCancelled() functions it turns out it is called in both cases. This is the log that happens after all the CHILD_ADDED Raising in both cases.

> D/EventRaiser(24587): Raising /users_data/google:XXX:CANCEL
>   D/FirebaseDataHelper(24587): onCancelled: message:  details:  code: -3 auth: google:XXX

The onCancelled:... line is Logged in the callback like this:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: message: " +firebaseError.getDetails() + " details: " + firebaseError.getDetails() + " code: " +firebaseError.getCode() + " auth: " + authData.getUid());
```

Here are the security rules for this node:

```
{ 
"rules": {
"users_data": {
  ".validate": "auth != null",
  "$user_id": {
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid",
    ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid"
  }
}
}
```

Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: It literally means that the Firebase client is about to raise a child_added event for that path. The most likely reason your handler is not invoked is because it isn't registered anymore at that time. If that's not is, is there any chance you can reproduce this in a minimal amount of code so that I can run it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there a way for me to check if the handler is not registered?

Comment: Not really. But I'd definitely put some logging in `onCancelled()` to see if you're getting cancelled for some reason (token expiration for example).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I update my question with more information about onCancelled calls. Thanks!

Comment: `public static final int PERMISSION_DENIED = -3;`

Comment: Yes. I saw that but why does this happen, every time the listener is set, but only sometimes the onChildAdded is not called? If I check the Firebase reference for authentication with getAuth(), the user is still authenticated in the onCancelled function.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you very much for your help. It looks like I was working with expired authentication. Firebase.getAuth() on start up seemed to return an authentication with expired token. I am re-authenticating every session now.